# How to retrieve one column value from one table using asp .net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, email

I have one table and i want to retrieve all the value from one column(mailid) .In the table two column are available that is id and mailid. 
I want to send mail to all the persons whose mail id is available in this column.

```
               mstEmpAdmin m = new mstEmpAdmin();


                var m2=(from e in db.mstEmpAdmins
                 select new
                 {
                     txtEmpAdminEmailId = e.txtEmpAdminEmailId,
                 });
                CustomMailService mail = new CustomMailService();

                string Subject = "Domestic Travel Request";
                string Body = "Hi Sir/Madam,My ";
                mail.Mail(m2,Subject, Body);
```

Form the above code it is showing error in last line ,what i am thinking is i will store al the mail id in one object then i will pass that object while sending mail.

Can I do like that ? Any solution for this ?

Comment: `mail.Mail(m2.txtEmpAdminEmailId, Subject, Body);`

Comment: thanks for your quick reply still it is showing error in the above line

Comment: Sorry, you need to add `.FirstOrDefault` (the query returns a collection but you only want one value)

Comment: no Stephen Muecke i want all the not single value...bcoz i need to send mail to all ....

Comment: What does the first parameter of `Mail` accept? Is it a collection? a comma separated list?

Comment: mail.Mail("abc@gmail.com", Subject, Body); it can accept like this

Comment: I mean how should it look if you have more that 1 address

Comment: mail.Mail(get_mstempinformation.txtEmailID, Subject, Body); it can accept like this also

Comment: please read my comments. Your query returns a collection. If you want to pass all the email addresses, what would it look like. For example is it a comma separated list as in `.Mail("abc@gmail.com, efg@gmail.com, xyz@gmail.com", Subject ...`?

Comment: it is accepting only 3 parameters

Comment: I know, but does the first parameter accept a comma separated list (or some other format) to send the email to multiple recipients? If not then you need a `foreach` loop on `m2` and create a separate email for each recipient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the output .

```
            List<mstEmpAdmin> adminlist = (from st in db.mstEmpAdmins
                                               select st).ToList();
                foreach (var item in adminlist)
                {

                    string Subject = "Request for Business Card";
                    string Body = "Hello Sir/Madam ," + "\n" + " " + bc.txtFirstName + " " + "You have requested for Business Card" + " " + "Total no of Quantity :" + bc.intQuantity + " ";
                    CustomMailService mail = new CustomMailService();

                    mail.Mail(item.txtEmpAdminEmailId, Subject, Body);
                }
```

Comment: Now I see what you actually want :)